# simple expression of trigonometric identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Trying to solve a math book exercise I draw a mental blank.
The problem is to express $\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$ in terms of $\cos4\theta$
Using the power reduction formulas
(and my basic understanding of simplifying them) I get:
            \begin{align*}
            \frac{1}{2}\left(1+\cos\left(2x\right)\right)\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos\left(2x\right)\right) &= \\
            \left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{cos(2x)}{2}\right) &= \\
           \frac{1}{4}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{4}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{4}-\frac{\cos(2x)^2}{4} &=
           \frac{1 - \cos(2x)^2}{4}
        \end{align*}
what seems to be the right track because the correct answer is:

$$\frac{1 - cos(4x)}{8}$$

and the graphs look exactly alike.
So in short, my question is how to get from $\frac{1 - \cos(2x)^2}{4}$ to $\frac{1 - cos(4x)}{8}$

I am aware that is is a very basic question but trying to self-teach me math fundamentals, I have to ask somewhere...

Comment: $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. If you use the double-angle formula for cosine, $\cos(2\theta)=\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$, then rearranging for $\cos^2(\theta)$ we have $\cos^2(\theta)=(1+\cos(2\theta))/2$. Now put $\theta=2x$ and you should be good.

Comment: I was confused by the `8` denominator, but replacing the expression with a fraction and applying the _divide fractions rule_ - it makes totally sense now...

Answer (score 1):

We know that:
$$\cos(4\theta)=1-2\sin^2(2\theta) \leftrightarrow sin^2(2\theta)=\frac{1-\cos(4\theta)}{2}$$
Now, we study $\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)$, that is the same as:
$$\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2\theta)$$
so:
$$4\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)=\sin^2(2\theta)$$
We can finally substitute and we have:
$$\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1-\cos(4\theta)}{8}$$

Comment: @michaPau: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach this problem:

$\cos (4 \theta) = 1-2\sin^2(2\theta)$

and

$\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$

so

$\cos (4 \theta) = 1-8\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)$

Re-arrange and you are done.